# I have to write "hello" to a file file.txt in assembly x86-64. This is what I got so far. No segmentation fault, but the file remains empty

Tags: assembly, printf, x86-64

I executed the following code, I get no segmentation fault, but the file remains empty and nothing is written into it. What is wrong with the code below?

```
.text


filename: .asciz "file.txt"
mode: .asciz "w"
message: .asciz "hello"
toChar: .asciz "%c"
toInt: .asciz "%u"


.global main



main:
    pushq   %rbp            
    movq    %rsp, %rbp      
    
    
    movq $filename , %rdi      
    movq $mode , %rsi         
    call fopen               

    movq $filename, %rdi    
    movq $message, %rsi
    call fprintf            

    movq $0, %rax
    movq $filename, %rdi 
    call fclose


    movq    %rbp, %rsp     
    popq    %rbp            
    movq    $0, %rdi        
    call    exit
```

Comment: `fclose` takes a `FILE*`, not a file name.  Also, `call exit` should come before `pop %rbp`; it follows the standard calling convention just like everything else, so it should be called with RSP%16 == 0 like for the other calls.  If you are going to tear down the stack frame you made, you could just `ret` from `main`, after `xor %eax,%eax` to return zero.

Comment: Easier to learn system & library calls, their usage & parameters in C.  You might consider doing this kind of thing in C first, with compiler help (and without assembly issues), and when you get that working, it is easily taken to assembly.

Answer (score 1):

Check the manual on `fprintf` and `fclose`.  These take the `FILE` pointer returned by `fopen` for arguments, not the file name as a string.  Edit your code such that it passes this pointer, e.g.:

```
        .align 8
file:   .quad 0

        ...
        movq $filename, %rdi
        movq $mode, %rsi
        call fopen

        mov %rax, file       # save a copy as rax is trashed by fprintf
        mov %rax, %rdi
        mov $message, %rsi
        xor %al, %al         # number of floating point arguments to fprintf
        call fprintf

        mov file, %rdi
        call fclose
```

Comment: Don't forget to put `file: .quad 0` in `.section .bss`.  The OP has their string constants in `.text`, which is read-only.  Or keep it in a call-preserved register like R12, then you don't have to show inefficient ways of accessing static storage (like `mov %rax, file` instead of `mov %rax, file(%rip)`.)  Also, `xor %eax,%eax` is a more efficient way to set AL=0.